# Which steps are needed to convert IDL to WSDL?

Tags: java, web-services, corba, idl

For my application I want to convert IDL to WSDL.

For that I have used some tools like Apache CXF, Jcorba4j, CorbaXscheme and many more but I am unable to convert.

How to create a WSDL from an IDL File?

I have used Apache CFX for IDL to WSDL (`idl2wsdl.bat`) but I don't know how to configure it. Can anyone guide me? Which tool I want to use so that I can get output?